# Why is there a "directory not empty" error in Podman when the step "RUN npm install" is executed?

Tags: reactjs, npm, wsl-2, podman

I am new to Podman, and I'm trying to run a React application with Podman using WSL Ubuntu.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
#build react app
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /home/dcaron/React-Admin\ Podman\ Test/client
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY public ./public
COPY src ./src

#RUN npm run build
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

When Podman gets to step 4 (RUN npm install), I get an error which states that the mount directory is not empty, which exits the procedure. Here are my console logs:

```
dcaron@R4ND0MCH4R5H3R3:~/React-Admin Podman Test/client$ sudo podman build -t react-test .
STEP 1/7: FROM node:lts-alpine
Resolved "node" as an alias (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/shortnames.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/node:lts-alpine...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob e8cf7b87eb8e done
Copying blob 9eb786875bee done
Copying blob e07f8c6b987e done
Copying blob b98e7fd986ed done
Copying config a9876edfcb done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
STEP 2/7: WORKDIR /home/carond1/React-Admin\ Podman\ Test/client
--> e98cdfbe90c
STEP 3/7: COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
--> ecb7df9e9c9
STEP 4/7: RUN npm install
WARN[0000] pkg/bind: error removing "/var/tmp/buildah13371337/mnt": directory not empty
ERRO[0000] directory not empty
error running container: error bind mounting root filesystem from "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/R4ND0MCH4R5H3R3R4ND0MCH4R5H3R3R4ND0MCH4R5H3R3R4ND0MCH4R5H3R3/merged" to "/var/tmp/buildah13371337/mnt/rootfs": invalid argument
Error: error building at STEP "RUN npm install": error while running runtime: exit status 1
```

Comment: Not an answer but why use such a convoluted `WORKDIR`? The container filesystem has nothing to do with the host. Keep it simple like `WORKDIR /app`

Comment: @Phil I did it because my eslint (or some other vscode addon) is configured to tell me to make filepaths absolute. You're probably right though.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if this was the fix, but my WSL Ubuntu was version 1, and after upgrading to version 2 this error disappeared.

Command:

`wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2`

Comment: I should also add that i should've done COPY . . instead of COPY ./src and COPY ./public, as my app was not working when launched in this manner until I made this change.

Comment: This fixed the same issue for me too, I think it's more than a coincidence.